# What does this “shell” belong to?

Tags: species-identification

I often find these, what I assume to be shells, during walks along the beach. I haven’t seen any creature or plant alive that has this feature and research attempts haven’t been successful.
There are bright reflective blue streaks along the shell and it is yellow-brown coloured and transparent. I have found these along the Northern Irish coast

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe it's a [Patella pellucida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patella_pellucida) or blue-rayed limpet. They live off seaweed in deeper waters, so it's not a surprise that you wouldn't see many live ones.

[image]

Picture from an interesting article: [Blue-rayed limpet holds secret for windscreen transparent displays with no internal light source](http://marketbusinessnews.com/blue-rayed-limpet-holds-secret-for-windscreen-transparent-displays-with-no-internal-light-source/50174)